# How to wrap span elements one below another next to a image?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a navbar which shows a profile picture, profile name and user's email. I want to know how to wrap the text and email next to the image. Just like fiddle's profile pic and name. Like the one in the link

[Like this](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-VPvU6tdfJds/Vx_6tPY7MPI/AAAAAAAAFdI/ODiiVGjTkykPquQOLG0PFX9moVh6FE43wCLcB/s1600/jsFiddle.jpg)

I tried this code. I am new to CSS and don't have a clue how to go about this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid top-bar-admin">
          <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{{url('/icons/logo.png')}}" id="cto_logo"></img></a>   
                </div>  
                <img id = "profile_pic" src = "https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">  
                <span id="int_profile_name">Jeni</span>
                <span>jeni@gmail.com</span>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp21zmj7/)

Answer (score 0):

try the break tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid top-bar-admin">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{{url('/icons/logo.png')}}" id="cto_logo"></img></a>   
            </div>  
            <img id = "profile_pic" src = "https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">  <br/>
            <span id="int_profile_name">Jeni</span><br/>
            <span>jeni@gmail.com</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: would setting the width of img and the spans to 100% work for what you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
navbar-header.img, navbar-header.span{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See update using flex:
Wrap your spans with a span tag like this:

```
 <span class="wraptext"></span>
```

Doesn't matter what class you give it.

Wrap your image with

```
<div class="flexit">
```

doesn't matter what class you give it.

As long as you target it with the correct css. See below:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/inspiraller/gp21zmj7/1/
```

**css**

```
.flexit{
  display:flex;
}
#profile_pic{
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.email{
  display:block
}
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid top-bar-admin">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>   
                </div>  
                <div class="flexit">


                   <img id = "profile_pic" src = "https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">  
                   <span class="wraptext">
                      <span id="int_profile_name">Jeni</span>
                      <span class="email">jeni@gmail.com</span>
                   </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add your text and email into div and give it `display: inline-block` which will make it appear beside the image.

to make the email in new line after the text just give one of them style `display: block` which will make it take the whole line.

for more info about what you want to do, you may need to read more about display property

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/ua9nouy6/) for what you want